# How does ASP.NET identify that the request is a postback?

Tags: asp.net, http

I am a bit curious how ASP.Net internally identifies that the request is a postback. 
I have read in a Microsoft book that you can technically do a postback using both POST and GET methods 
This means that commands do not have anything to do with postback.
I have tried to use Fiddler to see what the request headers are sending. I am thinking that it could be something to do with the viewstate but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly right.

The correct event is fired based on the _EVENTTARGET and _EVENTARGUMENT variables which are sent as part of the request. I believe the IsPostBack is set based on the values of these. These determine which event to fire and with what arguments.

The actual submit is fired by the `__doPostBack()` function in javascript.

More detail here: http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/haissam/archive/2007/05/18/Which-Control-Caused-PostBack_2100_.aspx